# Logout on listing of huge data with pagination using symfony 1.4

Tags: php, mysql, symfony-1.4

I have an application purely build on Symfony 1.4 and MySQL.

I have to deal with listing of around 25.000 items with pagination, and is done by "Stored Procedure (SP)".

The listing is working properly but after loading the page logout occurs. So can't go to any other options in the page. Instead of SP I have created views for the table entries and checked, but the problem is still there.

What will be the reason?

Comment: What does the symfony log toolbar say (the tab *logs*)? Can you spot a call to the logout action? Can you add it to your question?

Comment: thanks j0k, I can view the listing page, but when tries to do another actions, redirects to logout screen. in dev mode, I can see some are slow queries (8.8 secs)

Comment: Look at the log file in dev mode, to see what happend after clicking somewhere and beeing redirected to logout.

Comment: thanks j0k, it was because of somebody had set a session with a string of huge length. Not the issue of SP. sorry for the delay.

Comment: You should post an answer describing the solution and accept it :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It was not the problem related to my Stored procedure.

After running the SP, I used to concatenate the ids from result set and store the string in a session variable. Because of string having huge size, occurs error with the session variable.

Now I found solution that, to set the query conditions as a session variable and wherever I need it, I can call the SP with the same conditions. Hence it's solved.